# How can I setup 2 VPS can connect without using VPN which those VPS has already setup the ListenAddress to the VPN

Tags: ssh, openvpn

I have 2 VPS,
and those 2 VPS are setup OpenVPN, and we only can access it by connect to VPN, then ssh it to VPN gateway itself. I set it up from sshd_config by adding ListenAddress.

here's the example of my 2 VPS IP Address

First Server 
IP Address: 192.168.0.1
VPN Address: 192.170.0.1

sshd_config
ListenAddress 192.170.0.1

Second Server
IP Address: 170.168.0.1
VPN Address: 170.192.0.1

sshd_config
ListenAddress 170.192.0.1

now if I want to connect to the First Server, I need to connect to my OpenVPN in First Server, then ssh it using VPN Address which I have set in ListenAddress
so it should, root@192.170.0.1 and I can't connect using the original IP Address. 
Also for Second Server I did same to connect to the VPS. And All good with it, it's like what I want.

but, the issue now, I want to connect to my First Server from Second Server without need to connect to VPN of my First Server and maybe can directly connect to the server directly using the original IP Address

How can I do that?